# Which type of classes should not be serialized

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, objectoutputstream

[java.io.ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29) says "**Exceptions are thrown** for problems with the OutputStream and **for classes that should not be serialized**."

what does that mean... Which type classes should not be serialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what does that mean... Which type classes should not be serialized

It's poorly worded. What it means is that the class concerned doesn't implement `Serializable.`

Answer (score 3):

--->An object is serializable only if its class or its superclass implements the Serializable (or  Externalizable) interface.

--->An object is serializable (itself implements the Serializable interface) even if its superclass is not. However, the first superclass in the hierarchy of the serializable class, that does not implements Serializable interface, MUST have a no-arg constructor. If this is violated, readObject() will produce a java.io.InvalidClassException in runtime.

--->The no-arg contructor of every non-serializable superclass will run when an object is deserialized. However, the deserialized objects? constructor does not run when it is deserialized.

--->The class must be visible at the point of serialization.

--->All primitive types are serializable.

--->Transient fields (with transient modifier) are NOT serialized, (i.e., not saved or restored). A class that implements Serializable must mark transient fields of classes that do not support serialization (e.g., a file stream).

--->Static fields (with static modifier) are Not serialized.

--->If member vairiables of a serializable object reference to a non-serializable object, the code will compile but a RumtimeException will be thrown.

Comment: u r telling how to make a class serializable..... but the javadoc is saying it throws exceptions for the classes that should not be serialized (not which are not serialized only)

Comment: What's with the "-->" stuff?  It looks a bit daft to me :-)

Comment: Last sentence is incorrect. A `NotSerializableException` is thrown under this condition.